Unable to boot normally, screen displays mce error
The installed system version is Ubuntu 24.04
This will appear when the system is turned on after the installation is complete, and it is stuck here and cannot be operated (so I cannot copy the error message, sorry)

But if I install Ubuntu 22.04, I can boot into the system normally and use it.
If you need any information please let me know, thanks!

Can you edit the question to include (a) the CPU type (b) PC model or motherboard (c) type of memory. If one Ubuntu version can boot but not another, perhaps a Kernel issue with how the memory controller initialisation is performed, rather than a fault with the memory.
